# integrating Spring with thymeleaf views

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have simple doGet method in Spring:

```
@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        List<Category> categories = categoriesService.getCategories();
        req.setAttribute("categories", categories);

        if (!resp.isCommitted()) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("thymeleaf_views/categories.html").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
```

I can get html page. But its all content is not resolved((

```
<body>
        <div>
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <ul id="menu" style="list-style-type:none">
                <li th:each="category: ${categories}" th:text="${category.name}"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

When I try to load the page - it loads tags as it is - does not substitute tags with its content(( What can be  the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a TemplateResolver. E. g. like the way below:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean 
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}
}
```